# Bash while loop stops unexpectedly

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I'm analyzing two scripts with some behaviour I don't understand:

```
#/bin/bash
tijd=${1-60}
oud=`ls -l $MAIL`
while : ; do
   nieuw=`ls -l $MAIL`
   echo $oud $nieuw
   sleep $tijd
done | { read a b rest ; echo $a ; echo $b ; echo $rest ; }
```

The while loop in this script stops after one iteration.

```
#/bin/bash
tijd=${1-60}
oud=`ls -l $MAIL`
while : ; do
   nieuw=`ls -l $MAIL`
   echo $oud $nieuw
   sleep $tijd
done | cat
```

The while loop in this script is infinite.

What is the difference? I think it's something with the pipe and the brackets but I can't explain it.

Comment: [Don't use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to get the contents the `MAIL` directory. See

Comment: I said i was 'analyzing' two scripts. It's just an exercise on writing shell scripts, not a script to use for real. Anyway thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop with `read` after **pipe** is terminating after first iteration because of invocation of **SIGPIPE** signal which happens LHS of pipe writes to a pipe whose output is not read as there is no while loop around `read` on RHS).  YOur example with `cat` doesn't exit because `cat` **continuously** reads from input where as `read` **terminates** after reading one line.

To understand this behavior first reduce your example:

```
while : ; do pwd; done | { read -r line; echo $line; }
/Users/admin
```

So `read` terminated after first line. To verify this enable `pipefail` using:

```
set -o pipefail
```

and check exit status:

```
while : ; do pwd; done | { read -r line; echo "$line"; }
echo $?
141
```

Exist status `141` is due to `SIGPIPE`.

---

To fix this now change your `read` on RHS of pipe inside a while loop:

```
while : ; do pwd; sleep 5; done | { while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done; }
/Users/admin
/Users/admin
/Users/admin
```

And now you will not see command exiting at all since `while read` is continuously capturing all the data from LHS of pipe.

Comment: Alright, but why is the example with cat working. I throught cat also reads from standard input. What is the difference?
In my course I also saw an example with an awk statement after the pipe and that's working too. I don't see how read is so much different from cat or awk.

Comment: You must have seen a slightly different example. Neither `cat` nor `awk` would exit "voluntarily" as long as the `while` loop continue to produce output.

Comment: @WardVanAssche: It is because `cat` **continuously** reads from input where as `read` **terminates** after reading one line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ***{read a b rest; ..}*** block is executed only **once**, and that the read command reads **one line** of input, while you expect it to read many lines.

What you wanted to write is this:

```
#/bin/bash
tijd=${1-60}
oud=`ls -l $MAIL`
while read a b rest; do
  echo $a
  echo $b
  echo $rest
done < <(
  while : ; do
    nieuw=`ls -l $MAIL`
    echo $oud $nieuw
    sleep $tijd
  done
)
```

It is a more 'standard' way to do it. It also avoids using the **pipe |**, which forces the **{read ..}** block to run as a separate process, which then makes it impossible to **observe** the effects of the read command in your main shell.

And the **<( .. )** thing is called **process substitution**. It basically executes the contained block while capturing its output into a temporary file, and then returns that temporary file name.